# Wrong Number of Arguments or Invalid Property Assignment error in VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

hoping someone can help me out here.

I'm trying to put together some code that will hide rows based on the values of two cells.

My code is below:

```
 Sub hideSummaryDetailed()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


 'Hide all the Rows based on the selection for Summary/Detailed data linked to cell A1
 If Cells(1, 1) = 0 Then
    Rows("23:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 1 And Cells(10, 5) = "All" Then
    Rows("23:43").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("44:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 2 And Cells(10, 5) = "All" Then
    Rows("23:126").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("127:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 1 And Cells(10, 5) = "Cardiff" Then
    Rows("128:148").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("23:127, 149:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 2 And Cells(10, 5) = "Cardiff" Then
    Rows("128:232").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("23:127, 233:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 1 And Cells(10, 5) = "Swansea" Then
    Rows("233:253").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("23:232, 254:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 2 And Cells(10, 5) = "Swansea" Then
    Rows("233:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("23:232").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 1 And Cells(10, 5) = "Both" Then
    Rows("128:148, 233:253").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("23:127, 149:232, 254:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 ElseIf Cells(1, 1) = 2 And Cells(10, 5) = "Both" Then
    Rows("128:336").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("E11").Select
    Rows("23:127").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

 End If

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Range("E11").Select

 End Sub
```

However when I run it I keep getting an error saying Wrong Number of Arguments or Invalid Property Assignments, when I click ok it doesn't highlight any specific part of the code to point me in the direction.

I am pretty new to VBA and have searched a few forums for advice on this error but nothing I have tried has worked or I have not understood it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can put in break points to see where the error happens or put in some msgbox statements to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: @RobAnthony that's a compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution for the problem mentioned above.

I have re-factored code.

In below code replace SheetName "Sample" with the name of your sheet in workbook.

```
 Sub hideSummaryDetailed()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample")

 With ws

     'Hide all the Rows based on the selection for Summary/Detailed data linked to cell A1
     If .Cells(1, 1) = 0 Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 1 And .Cells(10, 5) = "All" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A44:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 2 And .Cells(10, 5) = "All" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A127:3A36").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 1 And .Cells(10, 5) = "Cardiff" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A23:A127, A149:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 2 And .Cells(10, 5) = "Cardiff" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A23:A127, A233:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 1 And .Cells(10, 5) = "Swansea" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A23:A232, A254:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 2 And .Cells(10, 5) = "Swansea" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A23:A232").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 1 And .Cells(10, 5) = "Both" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A23:A127, A149:A232, A254:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     ElseIf .Cells(1, 1) = 2 And .Cells(10, 5) = "Both" Then
        .Range("A23:A336").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Range("A23:A127").EntireRow.Hidden = True

     End If

 End With

 ws.Range("E11").Select

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not valid VBA code:

```
Rows("23:43").Select Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

Remember, a single line in VBA is a single command. The above line is two separate commands. This is valid VBA code:

```
Rows("23:43").Select 
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

However now we deal with the inefficiency of the code itself. You are using `ActiveSheet` implicitly, and you are relying on `Select`. For avoiding `Select` and `Activate` I would recommend starting here: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) .

How can we refactor this code? Simple:

```
' Near the beginning of the module....
Dim Target as Worksheet

' Ideally, explicitly set this to the correct worksheet. 
' For now, this will still use the Activesheet, it will just
' do it more explicitly and reliably since it won't potentially change as the code is running.
Set Target = ActiveSheet


' Later in the code....

' Notice how clean this is. We rely on Target instead of an implicit ActiveSheet, and we
' don't have to rely on the `EntireRow` property of `Selection` since we are explicitly accessing
' the rows.

Target.Rows("23:24").Hidden = False
```

This not only solves the error at hand, but it also helps you avoid many of the common errors that will cause countless hours of frustration and maintenance later.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, neither is Cells without a Worksheet, aka the syntax needs to be Worksheets("worksheet_name").Cells(a, b) rather than just Cells(a,b)

Comment: @acousticismX That is correct. Pretty much any time you are missing a higher-level reference on the left hand side you will want to see if it is properly qualified. Preferably, everything should be qualified up to the Workbook level.

Comment: thanks for confirming. it's been a while since I've done VBA.

Comment: I'm amazed that the single line of code that should be two compiles - doesn't run, but it compiles.  Being pedantic (what else would you expect from a coder) - you could have it as a single line if the commands are separated by a colon: `Rows("23:43").Select: Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False`.  But that makes it hard to read and 'tis silly.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Agreed. My initial reaction is `That shouldn't compiile` but sure enough it did. I thought of introducing the `:` line continuation token, but it causes far more grief than it is worth in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, great help!